# OpenTelemetry for short-lived scripts?

Tags: open-telemetry

Our system consists of many python scripts that are run on "clean" machines, that is, they need to have as little additional software on them as possible. Is there a way we could use OpenTelemetry without having to run additional servers on those machines? Is there a push model for sending data instead of pull?

Comment: What kind of telemetry are you planning to send?

Comment: I was thinking of starting with the start/finish events, then adding more, like successful completion/failure, etc., system utilization, logs, crash reports, etc. In general, we have none, we want all, but we are not yet quite sure what exactly we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your additional explanation I imagine you will eventually want to collect all telemetry from these systems. Using OTLP exporters you can send all three signals traces, metrics, logs to collector service (As of now only tracing is stable and metrics, logs work is experimental). You would not have to run any additional servers on these resource constrained servers for your use case. There are two deployments strategies recommended for opentelemetry collector.

1. As an agent - Runs along with the application on same host machine.
2. As a gateway - Runs on standalone server outside the application host machine.

Running collector agent on same application host machine offloads some of the work from language client libs and enhances the telemetry but can be resource incentive.

Read more about collector here https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/